# R shiny navbar to hamburger on small devices

Tags: r, shiny, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have a shiny app which should be responsive as we would like the end users to use it on laptop and ipad. Below is the navbar based layout for the shiny app. Now when I change the screen size I want the navbar menu to convert into a hamburger menu rather aligning one below other.

For eg : The end result I am looking for is like this :
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Bootstrap scrollspy on multiple tabs",
  id = "navbar",
  header = div(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs("www/app-shinyjs.js", functions = c("updateScrollspy")),
    includeCSS("www/app.css"),
    includeCSS("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"),
    includeScript("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"),
    includeScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.3/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
  ),

  # tab 1 contains 4 sections and a scrollspy on the left with text
  tabPanel(
    "tab1",
    div(id = "tab1-content",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            4,
            div(
              id = "tab1-scrollspy",
              class = "potential-scrollspy",
              tags$ul(
                class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked",
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section1-1", "Section 1-1")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section1-2", "Section 1-2")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section1-3", "Section 1-3")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section1-4", "Section 1-4"))
              )
            )
          ),
          column(
            8,
            div(id = "section1-1",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 1-1')
            ),
            div(id = "section1-2",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 1-2')
            ),
            div(id = "section1-3",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 1-3')
            ),
            div(id = "section1-4",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 1-4')
            )              
          )
        )
    )
  ),

  # tab 2 contains 3 sections and a scrollspy on the right without text
  tabPanel(
    "tab2",
    div(id = "tab2-content",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            8,
            div(id = "section2-1",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 2-1')
            ),
            div(id = "section2-2",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 2-2')
            ),
            div(id = "section2-3",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 2-3')
            )
          ),
          column(
            4,
            div(
              id = "tab2-scrollspy",
              class = "potential-scrollspy",
              `data-offset` = 50,
              tags$ul(
                class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked",
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section2-1")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section2-2")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section2-3"))
              )
            )
          )
        )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # when changing tabs, update the scrollspy control
  observeEvent(input$navbar, {
    js$updateScrollspy(input$navbar)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking into this now myself and it turns out there is simply an argument in the `navbarPage()` function that will do this for you:

```
navbarPage(..., collapsible = TRUE)
```

One may then test that it is working by (in Firefox) entering 'responsive design mode' by pressing Ctrl-Shift-M